# Data Retention Policy in MySQL RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it possible to implement a different data retention policy in master database (transnational database) and a slave database(Reports) ?
For example, we want to keep only 6 months of data on master and, 2 years of data on the slave. With ec2 instances it is possible. We can purge data after disabling the binary logs for the particular session.

As I know, It is not possible to disable binary logs for a session in an RDS instance. Do we have any workaround for this? We would like to schedule the purging script, so that master database contains only 6 months of data and slave contains only 2 years of data.

Thank you.

Comment: Set a column that says when the data was collected, then periodically delete anything that's old enough to be outside of the retention window.

Comment: Hi tadman. Yes, we can, but the problem is when we delete the data in the master, deletes will be propagated to the slave as well. We need to have a higher retention in the slaves to be used for reporting.

Comment: You could solve that by using something other than the default replication method to stream data to your data warehouse. A client that connects to both servers and transposes data is not hard to implement.